# Add column with a case in spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive

I have a data frame named `f` in Spark and I would like to add a column to it based on the case.
This is what I have tried:

```
df = f.withColumn('new_col', (case f.val when 1 then 'Y' when 0 then 'N' else null ))
```

Can anyone tell how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The `null` part makes this surprisingly hard. One solution is to create a `DataFrame` with your translation values, and do a `join` with `left_outer` against this:

```
val newDF = Seq(("Y",0)).toDF("srcVal", "newVal")
// +------+------+
// |srcVal|newVal|
// +------+------+
// |     Y|     0|
// +------+------+

val df = Seq((1,"Y"),(2,"N"),(3,"Y")).toDF("key","value")
// +---+-----+
// |key|value|
// +---+-----+
// |  1|    Y|
// |  2|    N|
// |  3|    Y|
// +---+-----+

val finalDf = df.join(newDF, $"value" === $"srcVal", "left_outer").drop($"srcVal")
// +---+-----+------+
// |key|value|newVal|
// +---+-----+------+
// |  1|    Y|     0|
// |  2|    N|  null|
// |  3|    Y|     0|
// +---+-----+------+
```